# window.onerror in TS 0.9.5 is impossible. :)

Tags: typescript

This very playground link used to work before TS 0.9.5 and now I can't figure out how to make it work for the life of me.

http://www.typescriptlang.org/Playground/#src=window.onerror=%20function%28eventOrMessage%3a%20any,%20source%3a%20string,%20fileno%3a%20number%29%7B%0A%09//%20place%20your%20body%20here%20%0A%7D;

Essentially:

```
window.onerror= function(eventOrMessage: any, source: string, fileno: number){
    // place your body here 
};
```

...returns an error:

> Error 8   Cannot convert '(eventOrMessage: any, source: string, fileno:
>   number) => void' to 'ErrorEventHandler':  Call signatures of types
>   '(eventOrMessage: any, source: string, fileno: number) => void' and
>   'ErrorEventHandler' are incompatible.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This looks like a bug in `lib.d.ts` to me (and possibly even the compiler) - because they have changed the definition of `ErrorEventHandler` in the latest branch.

In 0.9.5 it is:

```
interface ErrorEventHandler {
    (event: Event, source: string, fileno: number, columnNumber: number): void;
    (message: any, uri: string, lineNumber: number, columnNumber?: number): boolean;
}
```

But in the master branch it is:

```
interface ErrorEventHandler {
    (event: Event, source: string, fileno: number, columnNumber: number): void;
}
```

In the meantime, you could use the following hack (or edit your lib.d.ts file to update it).

```
interface TempErrorEventHandler {
    (event: Event, source: string, fileno: number, columnNumber: number): void;
}

var test1: TempErrorEventHandler =
    function (event: Event, source: string, fileno: number, columnNumber: number): void {

    }

window.onerror = <ErrorEventHandler> test1;
```

Comment: Dude, you're smart. So smart. I don't know enough about TS, but is it invalid to have two nameless methods like that?  How would window.onerror know which implementation to call?

Comment: The interface represents a function with two overloads - so TypeScript will inspect the parameter list to work out which of the two is being called (and will then know the appropriate return type too). I'm not clever - the TypeScript guys are incredibly smart though - the type inference in the compiler is super-awesome.

Comment: Steve and Basarat you've saved me frustration again!  BTW has this been raised as an issue on CodePlex?  I can see this: https://typescript.codeplex.com/workitem/1570 but this refers to 0.9.1.1.  I'm working around it for now but it would be good to get this fixed in TS proper.

Comment: Raised it on CodePlex here: https://typescript.codeplex.com/workitem/2062 as I couldn't see that it had been raised elsewhere...

Answer (score 5):

As Steve fenton mentioned. Alternatively you can use the common signature between the two functions:

```
window.onerror= function(eventOrMessage: any, source: string, fileno: number, colnumber?:number):any{
    // place your body here 
};
```

Comment: Thanks bassarat. I learned a few things from your answer and @steve-fenton. I put together this playground script that illustrates a couple of interesting things related to this question. http://bit.ly/18BvQ8v Your answer is cleaner, for sure, but Steve's answer does show off other ways to bend the language, and he was first, so I'm leaving his as the accepted answer.

Answer (score 0):

Based on basarat solution (I just add the optional error parameter, could be helpful):

```
window.onerror = function(errorMsg: any, url: string, lineNumber: number, colNumber: number, error: { stack?: string } = null) {
    // .. error handler
};
```